# How to edit the text in notes, simultaneously in (MongoDB) database too

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here in this code I have implemented the add note functionality and delete note functionality but I am not able to to edit or update a selected note. So, can anyone figure me this out ? Also simultaneously, the change should appear in database too. Help me out through it. If possible, share me the code and tell me that where should I implement it. Please.

**app.js**

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/NotesDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const itemsSchema = {
  name: String
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);


const item1 = new Item({
  name: "Welcome to Notes Keeper App!"
});

const item2 = new Item({
  name: "Hit the + button to add a new note."
});

const item3 = new Item({
  name: "<-- Hit this to delete a note."
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

const listSchema = {
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
};

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);


app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  Item.find({}, function(err, foundItems){

    if (foundItems.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully savevd default items to DB.");
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", {listTitle: "Notes Keeper App", newListItems: foundItems});
    }
  });

});

app.get("/:customListName", function(req, res){
  const customListName = _.capitalize(req.params.customListName);

  List.findOne({name: customListName}, function(err, foundList){
    if (!err){
      if (!foundList){
        //Create a new list
        const list = new List({
          name: customListName,
          items: defaultItems
        });
        list.save();
        res.redirect("/" + customListName);
      } else {
        //Show an existing list

        res.render("list", {listTitle: foundList.name, newListItems: foundList.items});
      }
    }
  });



});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });

  if (listName === "Notes Keeper App"){
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    List.findOne({name: listName}, function(err, foundList){
      foundList.items.push(item);
      foundList.save();
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    });
  }
});

app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  const listName = req.body.listName;

  if (listName === "Notes Keeper App") {
    Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err){
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Successfully deleted checked item.");
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    });
  } else {
    List.findOneAndUpdate({name: listName}, {$pull: {items: {_id: checkedItemId}}}, function(err, foundList){
      if (!err){
        res.redirect("/" + listName);
      }
    });
  }
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

**list.ejs**

```
<%- include("header") -%>

  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">

  <%  newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>

    <form action="/delete" method="post">
      <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <p><%=item.name%></p>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="listName" value="<%= listTitle %>"></input>
    </form>

  <%  }) %>

      <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Note ..." autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
      </form>
  </div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

Comment: So what's the problem with implementing update?

Comment: I am not able to implement update. If you have any idea about the update code please share the code.

Comment: Not able how? What stops you? Functionally, it's more or less a mix of find and create, which you have already implemented.

Comment: Yeah, but can you share the code for it ? I am a bit confused how to do it. Please